# Declaring multiple div selectors within jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, opacity, jquery-hover

Basically I'm working with a piece of jQuery that I'm using to control an image fade.

This piece of code, first identifies a div class of `.fade`, then connects a `.hover` to it.

When `.fade` is hovered over, an image within a `display:none` div within the `.fade` class is slowly faded in bringing opacity back to 1.

It's a fairly simple piece of code, but I'm wondering if there's a way to modify it in order to work with multiple classes (ie. fadetwo, fadethree, etc)... because it works off of a div within the parent `.fade` class it should work right?

I just can't seem to make it work. I'm trying to add additional classes in this line:

```
$('div.fade').hover(function()
```

Like:

```
$('div.fade, div.fadetwo, div.fadethree').hover(function()
```

I'm just trying to make so I can have multiple divs (`.fade`, `.fadetwo`, etc.) have that same hover effect (obviously each with different images)... I'm not sure if jQuery even works like this.

Possibly there is a better way to do this?... Beneath is my code.

http://jsfiddle.net/yvgFy/

Comment: yes. jQuery supports that no problem.

Comment: Also: your code on jsfiddle appears to work. I'm not sure what your error is?

Comment: Wow! it didn't work when I originally tried it, that's for sure...

Sorry about that! I'll try to find a way to close this, or mark it as answered!

Comment: perhaps the jsfiddle is the last working state and the OP tries to continue with more than one class.

Comment: @richie, welcome to Stack Overflow and sorry for the edits. Code formatting is important. If you present your question in a clear and structured way, you will get more help. You can use backquotes to format code fragments and indent by four spaces for code lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear whether you want to select with ALL three classes or with ONE of the three classes. Therefore I explain both possibilites:

**Select ALL classes**

Write your classes together without spaces and commas, like this:

```
$('div.fade.fadetwo.fadethree')
```

this selects only divs with all three classes.

**Select ONE of the classes**

If you need to select divs with one of the three classes, omit the spaces, like this:

```
$('div.fade,div.fadetwo,div.fadethree')
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the clarification! Good knowledge to have!

(and thanks for the welcome!)